# Correct Way of Using Timestamp When Accessing Marvel API in React Using Fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timestamp, fetch-api

What is the correct way of using the Timestamp (ts) param when accessing the Marvel API?
Some examples use ts=1 successfully but I haven't been able to get it to work.

I have even tried to use `let ts = Number(new Date())` but still no luck.

Can timestamp be a static number or should if be a variable that gets updated every time the API is accessed?

The way my url string looks like is as follows:

```
http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&apikey={myApikey}&hash={myHash}
```

Comment: According to the marvel api docs, a query parameter `ts` doesn't exist. https://developer.marvel.com/docs#!/public/getCreatorCollection_get_0

Comment: I just tried with my credentials and it worked fine, add `https` instead of `http`

Comment: @SamBokaiAre you sure?  Then what is the param to use for TimeStamp?   According to the 'Authorization' page the URL contains a `ts` param.

Comment: @S.Marx But what do you do for Timestamp?

Comment: @iChido hey! What I just did was copy your URL and add my `apiKey` and `hash`, the only different thing was that I used `https` instead of `http`. I used the `ts` param like you and it gave my the characters

Comment: @S.Marx Hey, thank you!  It's working fine for me too even though the ts value alone is always 1.  What no one seems to answer is what the TIMESTAMP should really be.  For now while I develop it will have to do but if I decide to move this "Fun Personal Project" to a live server I don't know if it will accepts the ts=1 value in the URL string. You know?  Anyway, thanks again! :D